# sortable bar chart in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm a newbie in d3.js and I'm trying to create a sortable bar chart. I'm following the example but I'm unable to get the same result. The bars move but the labels do not. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any guidance is hugely appreciated. Thanks

```
<label><input id="sort" type="checkbox"> Sort values</label>
<div id="check"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/d3-tip.js"></script>
<script>
debugger;

var data=@Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 40
},
width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;




var x=d3.scaleBand()
.rangeRound([0, width])
.padding(0.1);

var y=d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]);


var chart = d3.select("#check")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var tip=d3.tip()
       .attr("class","d3-tip")
       .offset([-10,0])
       .html(function(d){

 return "<strong>Rec Items:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" +        d.TotalRecItemsSum + "</span>"
 })


chart.call(tip)

x.domain(data.map(function(d){
    return d.AppClientName;
})) //x domain is a map of all client names

y.domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d){return d.TotalRecItemsSum;})])
//y is range from maximum(count) value in array until 0

chart.selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter().append("svg:rect")
.attr("x",function(d){
    return x(d.AppClientName);
})
.attr("class", "bar")

.attr("width",x.bandwidth())

.attr("y",function (d){
    return y(d.TotalRecItemsSum);})

.attr("height",function(d){
    return height-y(d.TotalRecItemsSum);})


.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)

var xAxis=d3.axisBottom().scale(x);

var yAxis=d3.axisLeft().scale(y);



chart.append("g")
.attr("class","y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("TotalRecItemSum");

chart.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")
.attr("transform","rotate(90)")//In some cases the labels will overlap
 //so I want to rotate the label's so they are vertical
.attr("x", 0) //After that some finetuning to align everything the right way:
.attr("y", -6)
.attr("dx", ".6em")
.attr("class","x axis")
.attr("class","text")
.style("text-anchor", "start")


d3.select("#sort").on("change", change);

var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("#sort").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);

function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

    // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
    var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
        ? function(a, b) { return b.TotalRecItemsSum - a.TotalRecItemsSum; }
       : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.AppClientName, b.AppClientName); })
        .map(function(d) { return d.AppClientName; }))
        .copy();

    chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(function(a, b) { return x0(a.AppClientName) - x0(b.AppClientName); });

    var transition = chart.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 100; };

    transition.selectAll(".bar")
        .delay(delay)     
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d.AppClientName); });



    transition.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("g")
        .delay(delay);
}
```

```
    <style>
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
         fill: none;
         stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
         }

.chart rect {
    stroke: white;
    fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
    fill: orangered;
}

.d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    .d3-tip:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        content: "\25BC";
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .d3-tip.n:after {
        margin: -1px 0 0 0;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }


.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}
```

I'm using d3 version 4. And in the above code, my x-axis has the client names and y-axis is a numerical value. So the bars are arranged in ascending order on checking the checkbox, only the labels do not move. Also, another issue is the checkbox gets checked automatically after a couple of seconds, that's happening because of var timeout, so should I be putting timeout inside function change?

Pls ask me any questions if my explanation is unclear, I always have trouble articulating. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add the x axis class to xAxis,  var xAxis=d3.axisBottom().scale(x).attr("class", "x axis");

Comment: This might help https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Sortable-Bar-Chart-Checkbox-1-Value it has a gh-pages demo also.